# Delete the duplicate rows but keep latest using JOINS throwing Error

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, sql-delete

I have tried all the ways to delete the duplicate data except one but all of them are taking a lot of time to query. But JOINS was the only one that took very less time. But here the issue is I am able to use select query. but delete is not working in pgadmin4 (PostgreSQL 14.0). how will I be able to resolve this issue.

```
 delete s1 FROM persons s1,
     persons s2 
where
      s1.personid > s2.personid
     AND s1.lastname = s2.lastname
order by personid desc
limit 100
```

It throws error saying "syntax error at or near "s1".
How can I solve this issue?

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|personid| firstname | lastname | email     |
|------------------------------------------ |
|   1       shanny      edward    shane@123 | 
| ------------------------------------------|
|   2       abc          way      abc@123   |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your sample data does not have an `id` column.  Please fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following exists logic when deleting:

```sql
DELETE
FROM persons p1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM persons p2
    WHERE p2.lastname = p1.lastname AND
          p2.personid < p1.personid
);
```

The above logic will spare, for each last name group of records, a single record having the smallest `personid` value.

Comment: thank you so much it worked but how can we limit to query rows based on Id?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.  I have answered what you actually did ask above.

Comment: I have added a sample table